# What's the difference between these two lines? (C#)

Tags: c#

In the following italicized code, why don't we put "IntIndexer" in front of *myData = new string[size];* since *Customer cust = new Customer();* (assuming Customer is the name of the class):

```
*Customer cust = new Customer();*
```

using System;

```
/// <summary>
///     A simple indexer example.
/// </summary>
class IntIndexer
{
    private string[] myData;

    public IntIndexer(int size)
    {
        *myData = new string[size];*

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myData[i] = "empty";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To break this down:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
```

This can be broken into two parts:

```
Customer cust;
cust = new Customer();
```

The first line says that the name `cust` will be able to refer to objects of type `Customer`. The second line creates a new `Customer` object and makes `cust` refer to it.

The other example you give is already broken into those two parts:

```
private string[] myData;
```

and:

```
myData = new string[size];
```

If the array of strings was to be of a constant length, we could collapse this onto one line as well, in `IntIndexer` (before the constructor).

```
private string[] myData = new string[100];
```

But we need to use the `size` passed into the `IntIndexer` constructor, so we have to split the declaration and initialization into two steps.

Answer (score 5):

The first line (`cust`) is declaring and initialising a field or variable.

In the second example, the field (`myData`) is declared against the type, and intialised in the constructor (`IntIndexer(...)`). If (in the constructor) we placed a type before it, we would be declaring a local variable **with the same name**. This would be confusing (you'd then have to use `this.myData` and `myData` to refer to the field and variable respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put a call to a constructor within itself?  As in if you want to instantiate IntIndexer you have to call this function and repeat the process until either you realize this will cause a stack overflow or just never terminate as it will always be trying to create the nth instance as n just keeps going and going up.

What am I missing in your example if I simply trace it that way?

Answer (score 0):

They're two different things.  myData has been declared as type `string[]`, not of type `IntIndexer`.

The class `IntIndexer` contains a variable called `myData`.  They are not equivalent.

You also wouldn't put the type in front of that line of code anyway, because you'd be redeclaring the variable.  Doing so would give you a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

myData is already declared as a field of IntIndexer class, so you don't have to redeclare it in the constructor. The class understands that it is referencing its own field.